# Can't Read Environment Variable $HOME inside VSCode ROS Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, ros, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I have a very simple launch file such as shown below:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="dataset_dir" default="$(env HOME)/mnist" doc="location to the dataset" />
  <node name="listener" pkg="package_a" type="listener.py" output="screen"/>
  <node name="talker" pkg="package_a" type="talker" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

While running inside VSCode ROS Debugger, it shows following error:

[image]

Please see the content of `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ROS: Launch",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "/home/ravi/catkin_ws/src/package_a/launch/bringup.launch",
            "type": "ros"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The code works fine in normal terminal but shows error inside VSCode.**

I am using VSCode v1.62.3 on ROS Melodic inside Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS OS.

Comment: What if you try `${env:HOME}` form instead?

Comment: @Mark: `${env:HOME}` stays as it is and `HOME` does not expand to `/home/user`

Answer (score 3):

This is being tracked under https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/issues/566.
If you launch `code` from your terminal window, it will inherit environment variables. Or you can add an 'env' option to the launch configuration such as:

```
        {
            "name": "ROS: Launch",
            "request": "launch",
            "env": [
              "HOME": "/home/ravi"
            ]
            "target": "/home/ravi/catkin_ws/src/package_a/launch/bringup.launch",
            "type": "ros"
        }
```

Comment: (1) I tried adding `env` option inside the launch configuration. But it didn't work. I think `env` should be a dictionary instead of a list. Please confirm. (2) I l launched `code` from a terminal after sourcing `setup.bash` for the ROS and its workspace. But still, the same error appears. Please confirm.